# Can I use SSL certificates in BIRT 4.7 Report Designer to connect to MySQL?

Tags: java, mysql, ssl, birt

Is possible create a data source with data stored in `MySQL` database and configure SSL certificates in the connection string? I have not found where I could set up it.

I have read the "`Birt report developer guide`", however, it does not mention anything about how to handle SSL connections.

If it is not possible, what approach do you recommend to connect to `MySQL` Database server that use SSL certificates?

BIRT Configuration:
[image]